# Remove sibling when image loads

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="image_inner imageFill6"></div>
    <img class="listImage" src="/images/production/5562.jpg">
</div>
```

I want the div with class `.image_inner` to fade out when image with class `.listImage` loads.

There will be many of these instances on a page.

This is what I'm trying but it doesn't fade out `.image_inner`

```
$(window).on('load', function() { 
    $(".listImage").on('load', function () {
        $(this).siblings('.image_inner').fadeOut();
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is when window load event is fired all the images are already loaded, so their load event won't be fired again. Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".listImage").on('load', function () {
        $(this).siblings('.image_inner').fadeOut();
    }).filter(function () {
        //trigger the load event for images which are already loaded
        retun this.complete;
    }).trigger('load');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the considerable warnings in the jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Are you confident that you're able to overcome these?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine.

```
$(".listImage").on('load', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.image_inner').fadeOut();
});
```

You will need to call the JS at the end of the body. Please have a look at the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/giri_jeedigunta/3vkXQ/